# Let $K<G$, where G is a group. Define $N_G(K)=(g\in G/gkg^{-1}=K)$ Prove the following:

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $K<G$, where G is a group. Define $$N_G(K)= \{g\in G \mid g K g^{-1}=K\}$$ which is called the normalizer of subgroup K.

1.) Prove that $N_G(K)$ is a subgroup of G and K is a normal subgroup of $N_G(K)$

2.) Prove that $K$ is a normal subgroup if and only if $N_G(K)=G$

The term normalizer is new to me but I take it that it follows the same principles of a normal group. So, therefore, I'm thinking that to prove this, I must try and prove that $K$ is a subset of $N_G(K)$ for every $k \in K$ where $kKk^{-1}=K$ for $N_G(K)$ I'm assuming that if I can do this, then it will help with solving part 2)

Comment: You're making it sound more difficult than necessary to show $K\subseteq N_G(K)$. Since for any $k \in K$ we have $kKk^{-1} = K$, it's clear that $k \in N_G(K)$.

Comment: @Arthur, this is the way that the question was presented to me. I get confused as it with notation, maybe that is why I was having problems with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, you just need to show that if $h$ normalizes $K$, then its inverse $h^{-1}$ does as well, and that if $g$ also normalizes $K$, then the product $hg$ normalizes $K$. This will show that the set $N_G(K)$ is indeed a group; it contains inverses and products of all its elements.

Think about why it's clear that $K \subseteq N_G(K)$, I'm not sure it's too helpful here.

I'll also say that the definition of $N_G(K)$ basically tells you why $K$ is normal in $N_G(K)$, so the 1st part should be the most difficult.

Comment: would it suffice to show that $N_G(K)$ and non-empty and closed under multiplication??

Comment: @cele Be careful, I fell into that trap on an exam. That holds for finite subgroups only. Since I don't see anything here about the group being finite, I'd go the extra mile and show that the normalizer contains inverses of its elements.

Answer (score 1):

$$K\lhd G\iff \;\forall\,g\in G\;,\;\;K^g= K\iff\,\forall\,g\in G\;,\;\;g\in N_G(K)$$

Comment: Of course this correct, but the second $\iff$ would be clearer if the second clause is written as $\forall g \in G, K^{g} = K$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Indeed so. I just read the definition given by the OP. I think things shall be clearer with your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Timbuc, is there a special meaning of the notation $K^g$ other than the obvious?

Comment: @cele Within group theory I don't think so.

Comment: @cele I think one nice thing about the notation is that it makes sense to pronounce it as "The image of $K$ under $g$. Here you're thinking of conjugation as a map, $\cdot^g: x \mapsto gxg^{-1} = x^g$.